# broadcast to room not working in disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to inform other client in the room when someone gets disconnected.

Here is my code:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
    var user = authedUsers[socket.id];
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: user, message: user.display_name + ' has been disconnected.'});
});
```

But I am getting this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: May be wrong, but I think when someone the disconnect event is called, the socket is already disconnected. But the error is about call stack size, so it may be somewhere else in the code, are you sure the eror happen here?

Comment: Yes i think so. Because the error only occurs when it process this part: socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: user, message: user.display_name + ' has been disconnected.'});

Comment: Call stack size is like a stack overflow error, signifying that you're calling many and many time (too much in reality) a function. Can you post your full code to help us understand ? Does your user.room really exist ?

Comment: @DrakaSAN you're right, the socket is already closed in socket.on('disconnect'). So socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit(); will not work. Skahrz you're also right. It is repeatedly trying to broadcast but it cannot find the socket and room that's why i had that error. I got it working using io.sockets.in(user.room).emit(). Thank you both!

Comment: I found out the reason. It is because the object user is too big. Maybe socket.io doesn't allow passing objects that are too big.
Now this is working:
socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: {ID: user.ID, display_name: user.display_name}, message: user.display_name + ' has been disconnected.'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that when the event disconnect is called, the socket is already closed.

So when you call the buggy line, it search to send with a closed socket, and for some reason end up making a call stack overflow.

You should send the message of deconnection before deconnecting the socket : )

Comment: Thank you for making me realize that. I had it working now using io.sockets.in(user.room).emit() :)
But now you got me curious, is it possible to send message of disconnection before socket.on('disconnect')? Is there pre-disconnect? :D

Comment: Well, if you can find where and why the socket disconnect, you should be able to send the message, yes. I ll start by when the user wish to disconnect.